# with what can substitute number >> in vim ?

Tags: vim

I  want to insert 8 blanks  at the front of many lines of code,
my cursor is in the front of `if strftime()` ,i want to add 8 blanks in all lines from  `if strftime()` till `endif`,

```
13>>   #count how many lines behind the cursor ,and `number >>`  can do.
```

I don't want to count  how many lines behind the cursor ,is there simple way to do that?

[image]

Comment: visual selection? then press `>`

Comment: With languages delimiting blocks with `{` and `}` you can use `=%` on either block delimiter for autoindenting that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do in such cases:

1. put your cursor at the beginning of the start line of the block you want to select , then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in GVim) to get into visual mode
2. use <kbd>j</kbd> to move the cursor down till the end line of the block
3. <kbd>I</kbd> (capital) get to edit mode
4. insert two tabs
5. press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to apply the change to all the previous selected lines

I tried another option it also works for me:

1. `:set nu`  to display the line numbers
2. `:34,46>>`  then the lines in the range between line 34 and 46 would do the `>>` change, you can change the two line numbers to yours in your case.

Comment: i am in gvim ,i tried what you provide the first method,strp 5 `press ESC to apply the change to all the previous selected lines` is not neccecary.

Answer (score 1):

Using `>>` with a count, if you turn on relative line numbering (`:set relativenumber`), you can get the count of lines very easily.

Or, use `>` instead of `>>`, which takes a motion command afterward. If there is a blank line after your block, just use `>}` to indent up to the blank line. Or it could be a search, like `>/endif<Enter>`.

Or visually select what you want and press `>` once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it simply without having to estimate the lines.

1. Start the cursor on the first or last line to indent
2. put VI in visual mode using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
3. move the cursor to the other end of the block to indent
4. hit <kbd>></kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way using marks:

1. Position your cursor at the beginning of the first line where you want to insert the blanks, perhaps by typing `/if (strftime/` in command mode. Now type <kbd>m</kbd> followed by any letter to set the mark with that letter as a reference. For example, I typed <kbd>m</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> to set mark 'a'.
2. Position your cursor at the beginning of the last line where you want to insert blanks. Now set a mark using a different letter (I used mark 'b'.)

Now as your question is unclear about whether you want to shift the lines by inserting 8 blanks at the start or whether you actually want to shift the line using the shift command 8 times, I'll answer with both:

- Shift by `shiftwidth` 8 times:

  ```
  :'a,'b>>>>>>>>
  ```

  The quantity of `>` characters is the number of times to shift (8 in this case), and `'a` and `'b` are the mark names preceded by the <kbd>'</kbd> character.
- Shift by inserting 8 leading spaces: type

  ```
  :'a,'bs/^/        /
  ```

  Yes, the spaces must be typed out fully.

Answer (score 0):

Open file in visual mode by pressing `v`

now select the block of code you want to modify

press `>` to insert a tab at the beginning of each line of selected  block.
and you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` command takes a `{motion}` that selects the range of lines to be indented. Now for Vimscript's `if...endif`, the *matchit.vim* plugin (that ships with Vim, see `:help matchit`) adds cycling through those. As you have `else` clauses in between, you need to use the reverse `g%` motion to cycle backwards to the final `endif`.

So, the shortest command to indent is `>g%`.